# Generated File Data Not Shown in Download File through Ajax request asp.net core

Tags: json, ajax, file, download

Downloaded a File through Ajax Request and here is my code

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: vGenerateUrl,
        data: { IDs: ids, SupplyType:supplyType, SubType:subType, DocType:docType, TransMode:transMode },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
             
            DevExpress.ui.notify({ message: "xyz Generated", width: 1300 }, vSuccessMsgType, 3000);
            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/json' });
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.download = 'a.json';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
        },
        error: function(result) {
            onAjaxError(result);
        }
    });
```

In Ajax Success, data which I have received is show in console properly but when I download file, there is no data in that file except [Object Object].

How do I get data in my downloaded file?

[image: File Data in Console]

[image: Downloaded Json File]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `data` is an object, you should convert it to a josn string before you create a blob from it.

```
var blob = new Blob([JSON.strinify(data)], { type: 'application/json' });
```